# Spring Boot + Ionic application authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, authentication

I am developing a hybrid application with the use of Ionic 3 which will communicate with a REST Api service that I will write with the use of Spring Boot.

I am having some difficulties with setting up a proper registration / login mechanism. What I want to achieve is that the user registers on the mobile application, then logs in with his username and password and then whenever he opens the app he will always be logged in (without the need to pass the credentials again) for as long as he does not click the "log out" button.

The way I have tried is that with the help of Spring Secutiry when the user logs in with his credentials he receives a JWT token which is saved on the client side (app side) and then used in the header for each subseqnet request.

The problem that I have with this solution is that I have to setup the JWT expiration date (like 10 days, 30 days) and then, when that time passes, the user will have to enter his credentials again in order to receive a new token. I would like to avoid that. Another issue is that there is no mechanism to invalidate JWT tokens in case there is such a necesity.

Another option would be I think to set the access token validty for like 30 minutes and then receive a new one with the refresh token. This however, requires also the client id and client secret, which again, I don't think are safe for storing in the client application.

What is the best practice for such a case?
Please help and thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Storage module from Ionic can be helpful.

Idea : First time send authentication request
If data is authenticated save the response in local storage (Basically user data)
If user logs out you can remove the storage.

More information can be found on
[Ionic Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/)

Comment: hey, well the storing of the token in the app is not the main problem here. The problem is the backend mechanism for generating the token and refreshing it